# how to find out which SATA port a disk is connected to on Windows 7

Tags: windows, wmi

I already tried the SCSIPort etc properties of Win32_DiskDrive (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132.aspx) but they totally vary between systems with identical setup and are not reliable.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: At least it depends on your driver. For example Intel's driver and MS's generic msahci driver behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver where DeviceName = 'Disk drive'
```

If i am not wrong, you are looking for **Location**

Output:

```
instance of Win32_PnPSignedDriver
{
    ClassGuid = "{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}";
    CompatID = "SCSI\\Disk";
    Description = "Disk drive";
    DeviceClass = "DISKDRIVE";
    DeviceID = "SCSI\\DISK&VEN_EQLOGIC&PROD_100E-00\\1&1C121344&0&000000";
    DeviceName = "Disk drive";
    DevLoader = NULL;
    DriverDate = "20060621000000.******+***";
    DriverName = NULL;
    DriverProviderName = "Microsoft";
    DriverVersion = "6.1.7601.19133";
    FriendlyName = "EQLOGIC 100E-00 SCSI Disk Device";
    HardWareID = "SCSI\\DiskEQLOGIC_100E-00_________5.2_";
    InfName = "disk.inf";
    IsSigned = TRUE;
    Location = "Bus Number 0, Target Id 0, LUN 0";
    Manufacturer = "(Standard disk drives)";
    PDO = "\\Device\\00000089";
    Signer = "Microsoft Windows";
};
```